How to setup a celery worker to consume high priority tasks only?
Celery allow to route tasks by task-name to avoid a load from a kind of task to delay tasks from other kinds.
Celery also handle priority with manual scale (often 0 : top priority -> 10 : lowest priority).
Priority can be set when you queue the task
my_task.apply_async(args=("daily task",), priority=7)
my_task.apply_async(args=("user interaction task",), priority=2)

This way, a same given task can have a different priority if it's called from a user interaction or from a background task.
My idea of what would be nice would be for example having a priority worker which would only process tasks with priority below a given threshold (ex 5) and a normal worker handling any task (including high priority ones). It would avoid having any issue to have many long runtime tasks with low priority as it would not increase latency of latency critical tasks.
Is this even possible ?

As far as I know this is not possible at the moment.
